# Finding sequence for generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the generating function

$$F(x) = \frac{x^3}{1 - x^2}$$

and I need to determine the sequence generated by it.

I know that the first non-zero term will be $x^3$, since that's the numerator. But I'm not sure how to determine the rest of the sequence.

Comment: **Hint**: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is known that 
$$1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots=\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}$$
for $|x|<1$.

Comment: But since x^3 isn't in that sequence at all, how do you find the sequence?

Comment: distribute $x^3$ along series terms and see the coefficients... did you see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series++x%5E3+%2F+%281+-+x%5E2%29+at+the+origin ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think I understand now - thank you!

Comment: cool! it would be pleasant to receive an upvote ;), i'm upvoting you

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$[x^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2} \right) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1 & n \text{ even} \\
0 & n \text{ odd} \end{array}
 \right.$$
when we multiply by $x^3$ we find that $F(x)$ is the generating function for
$$ a_i = \left\{ 0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots \right\} =\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1 & i \text{ odd},  i > 2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{array}
 \right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Apply partial fractions;

$$\frac{x^3}{1-x^2} = -x-\frac{1}{2 (x-1)}-\frac{1}{2 (x+1)}$$